# Error en cargar busqueda de select2

Tags: javascript, modal, select2

Tengo el siguiente problema, al seleccionar el select2, me muestra los datos  del  pero no me permite realizar la busqueda. No me deja ingresar datos ni nada, sino hasta luego de cierto tiempo que aparece una pequeña modal de inactividad, y cuando muevo el mouse para quitar el cuadro de inactividad ya me permite realizar la busqueda en el select2

Esto esta dentro de una modal. Al darle click antes a un botón se despliega la modal, la cual tiene los datos de cotizaciones y despliega el select, y es ahi donde no me permite realizar la busqueda

¿Como puedo solucionarlo? En el código que adjunto tal parece que me lo muestra correctamente, pero ya en mi código no me permite hacer la búsqueda con el select2

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
$("#mdl_add_cotizacion").select2();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="mdlAddRemisiones" name="mdlAddRemisiones" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mdlAddRemisiones" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form name="frm_add_remision" id="frm_add_remision">
                
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <p class="col-md-8" id="myModalLabelNombre" style="text-align: left;">Nueva Remisión</p>
                    <p class="col-md-2 ml-auto" id="myModalLabelId" style="text-align: right;">No. ID:</p>
                    <p class="col-md-2 ml-auto" id="myModalLabelCodigo" style="text-align: left;">001</p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">                
                    <p class="mdlSeccion" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align: left;">Datos Cotización</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="mdl_add_cotizacion" id="mdl_add_cotizacion" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
                                    <option value="1">M-001</option>
                                    <option value="2">M-002</option>
                                    <option value="3">M-003</option>
                                    <option value="4">M-004</option>
                                </select>
                                <label>Número de Cotización</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="button" id="btnAddCotizacion" class="btnAgregar">Agregar Cotización</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="loadDetalle" style="margin-top: -1em;"></div>
                    <div id="loadProductos" style="margin-top: -1em;"></div>
                    <div id="loadTabla" style="margin-top: -1em;"></div>

                </div>                
                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnCancelar" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnAddLimpiar" class="btnAddLimpiar">Imprimir Remisión</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnAgregar" class="btnAgregar" onclick="finalizarRemision(001, 'rem')">Finalizar Remisión</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Imagen de la modal con el select]